# CakePHP: List all Controllers using Component X

Tags: cakephp, components, cakephp-2.3, controllers

Long story short: How do I get all controllers of my app that use a certain component.

The story: I have multiple controllers in my app, some of them using a component.

```
public $components = array('MyPlugin.MyComponent');
```

Is there a way, in the component or elsewhere, to find out which controllers include this component so I can list them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it seems to be quite simple, but I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it, as it seems pretty hacky to me:

```
$controllers = App::objects('controller');
foreach($controllers as $controller) {
    App::import('Controller', str_replace('Controller', '', $controller));
    $properties = get_class_vars($controller);

    if(isset($properties['components']) && (isset($properties['components']['MyPlugin.MyComponent']) || in_array('MyPlugin.MyComponent', $properties['components']))) {
        $this->editable[] = str_replace('Controller', '', $controller);
    }
}
```

Any better solution out there?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so since components are loaded to currently active controller.

When user enters url it is resolved on server side by CakePHP to on of your controllers and only this one is created for this request.

In order to try find Controllers using some component you can search for all controllers by [App::objects('Controller')](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-App.html#_objects) then you can try to instantiate each Controller and read it's `$components` property. Which is pretty much the same which you proposed in you answer and is also a bit hacky (but can take take base class parameters IMO).